# Pip install giving SyntaxError in Anaconda

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I installed anaconda2 over python 2.7 and i am on Windows 10.
when I am trying to use pip , Syntax error is coming. I am using basic cmd to access pip , even without the environment variable thing , it's not working . 
Can anybody explain what am I doing wrong  ?

Error:

```
C:\Users\Yash gupta\Anaconda2\Scripts>python
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:17:26) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> pip install bs4
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install bs4
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using pip in python environment.

You must quit python and run `pip install bs4` with the shell.

If you want to install the library only in a specific anaconda environment, lunch the `source activate <yourEnv>` command and then use `pip install`.

Comment: when i used to use just python , pip used to work . can u explain that?

Plus  I tried your method new error came : 

ImportError: No module named urllib3

Comment: urllib its an other package, use `pip install urllib3`

Comment: You must own all the packages you want to import

Comment: If you are using a specific conda env, you must install all the packages you need, in this conda env. For that, enter the command `source activate <yourEnv>`and THEN use `pip install`, so that, the package will be installed in the specific conda env